# Couchbase data flagged for deletion

Tags: couchbase

When a deletion query is executed in couchbase it flags the resulting documents for deletion.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/dev-guide-3.0/delete-info.html

Is there a way to stop the process and remove this flag?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Take a look into this [couchBase forum question](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/question-about-document-deletion/8731/3) it may help you